# Subeqnarray: adding left aligned text without affecting centering of equations

Tags: equations, align, labels

I have a code which generates two equations on the same line by using the subeqnarray package.

[image]

I am now interested in adding text in the same line as these equations, but aligned to the left of the page without affecting the centering of the equations.  Assuming I would like to write Case 1, it would look like this:

```
         Case 1                      a = 0,   b = 1,              1(a-b)
```

Can I do this using the subeqnarray package?

Thanks in advance!

CODE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,default]{amsart}
\usepackage{subeqnarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{subeqnarray}
\gdef\thesubequation{\theequation \textit{a-b}}
a = 0,  \qquad \quad
b = 1,
\end{subeqnarray}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: I have been asked to make the question clearer -- I appreciate the feedback!

Look forward to your comments

Comment: As always on this site, please add a full (but minimal) example instead of a sniplet like this. Then those wanting to help does not have to guess 1/3 of a document. It is not even clear how `Case 1` comes into this.

Comment: Also remember that anythng even remotely similar to `eqnarray` should not be used.

Comment: Edited after being put on hold! Hope this is clearer - let me know what you think!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, if the following solution is acceptable for you:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
c^2 = a^2 + b^2
\end{equation}
\begin{flalign}\refstepcounter{equation}
\text{Case 1}   &&
    a = 0,  \qquad \quad
    b = 1,      &&  \tag{\theequation $a$-$b$}
                    \label{eq:case-1}
\end{flalign}
With the \eqref{eq:case-1} we can derive:
\begin{equation}
c = 1
\end{equation}
See \ref{eq:case-1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks a lot!